# Problema de arquitetura onde o acesso a métodos de construção devem ser controlados

Tags: c#, design-pattern

Tenho uma classe para árvore que terá a adição de troncos, galhos, folhas e frutos.

Preciso que a classe dê acesso a determinados métodos somente após outros e que aos anteriores não possa haver acesso novamente.

Exemplo:

```cs
public class Arvore 
{ 
    public List<Membro> Membros { get; set; }

    public Arvore AdicionarTronco()
    {
        Membros.Add(new Tronco());
        return this;
    }

    public Arvore AdicionarGalho()
    {
        Membros.Add(new Galho());
        return this;
    }

    public Arvore AdicionarFolha()
    {
        Membros.Add(new Folha());
        return this;
    }

    public Arvore AdicionarFruto()
    {
        Membros.Add(new Fruto());
        return this;
    }

    public void ImprimirArvore() { ... }
}
```

Então o problema é que, após a criação de `Arvore`, os único método que possa ser acessado é `AdicionarTronco()`.

Após `AdicionarTronco()`, somente `AdicionarGalho()` poderá ser acessado, e `AdicionarTronco()` não poderá mais ser acessado.

Por fim, `AdicionarFolha()` e `AdicionarFruto()` poderão ser acessados, mas não poderão acessar os outros métodos.

Preciso dar o seguinte exemplo de funcionalidade para a classe:

```cs
(new Arvore())
    .AdicionarTronco()
    .AdicionarGalho()
    .AdicionarFolha()
    .AdicionarFruto()
    .ImprimirArvore();
```

Para isso pensei então em controlar o acesso aos métodos por meio de interfaces, e pensei:

```cs
public interface IArvore
{
    ITronco AdicionarTronco();
    void ImprimirArvore();
}

public interface ITronco
{
    IGalho AdicionarGalho();
}

public interface IGalho
{
    IGalho AdicionarFolha();
    IGalho AdicionarFruto();
}
```

Daí, fazer a classe `Arvore` descender das interfaces:

```cs
public class Arvore : IArvore, ITronco, IGalho
{
    public List<Membro> Membros { get; set; }

    public ITronco AdicionarTronco()
    {
        Membros.Add(new Tronco());
        return this;
    }

    public IGalho AdicionarGalho()
    {
        Membros.Add(new Galho());
        return this;
    }

    public IGalho AdicionarFolha()
    {
        Membros.Add(new Folha());
        return this;
    }

    public IGalho AdicionarFruto()
    {
        Membros.Add(new Fruto());
        return this;
    }

    public void ImprimirArvore() { ... }
}
```

Mas ainda assim consegui resolver pouco.
Consegui resolver a questão de não conseguir voltar aos métodos, mas pela `Arvore` ainda tenho acesso aos métodos `AdicionarGalho()`, `AdicionarFolha()` e `AdicionarFruto()`.

Ainda assim, no fim preciso ter acesso ao método `ImprimirArvore()`.

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Eu imagino que você não está realmente modelando árvores em C#. Você se incomoda de dar detalhes sobre o domínio ao qual essa solução se aplicaria?

Comment: @ctgPi é só uma questão da faculdade que estava com dificuldade de entender.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esse tipo de problema pode ser resolvido recorrendo ao [*Composite Design Pattern*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite)

> Composite é um padrão de projeto de software utilizado para representar um objeto que é constituído pela composição de objetos similares a ele. Neste padrão, o objeto composto possui um conjunto de outros objetos que estão na mesma hierarquia de classes a que ele pertence.

Comecemos por escrever uma classe abstracta que servirá de base para todos os membros do compósito:

O construtor recebe o nome deste Membro(Arvore, Tronco, etc) e declara dois métodos virtuais:

**AdicionarMembro** - Adiciona membros a este Membro. Nos níveis mais baixos do compósito é lançada uma Excepção por não ser permitido a sua adição(Folha e Fruto)

**Imprimir** - Imprime o nome deste Membro

```
public abstract class Membro
{
    protected readonly string _nome ;

    protected Membro(string nome)
    {
        _nome = nome;
    }

    public virtual string Nome
    {
        get { return _nome; }
    }

    public virtual void AdicionarMembro(Membro membro)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Não podem ser adicionados membros ao membro " + Nome);
    }

    public virtual void Imprimir(int nivel)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new String('-', nivel) + Nome);
    }
}
```

Necessitamos de uma classe para os Membros que têm membros(Arvore, Tronco e Galho). Será uma classe abstracta e herdará de *Membro*.

A classe declara uma lista onde serão guardados os Membros que o compõem.
Os métodos `AdicionarMembro()` e `Imprimir()` foram reescritos, o primeiro de forma a adicionar os novos membros à lista, o segundo de modo a imprimir também os nomes dos membros filhos.

```
public abstract class MembroComposto : Membro
{
    protected IList<Membro> _membros;
    protected MembroComposto(string nome) : base(nome)
    {
        _membros = new List<Membro>();
    }

    public override void AdicionarMembro(Membro membro)
    {
        _membros.Add(membro);
    }

    public override void Imprimir(int nivel)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new String('-', nivel) + Nome);
        foreach (var membro in _membros)
        {
            membro.Imprimir(nivel + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Estas duas classes são a base para a implementação do *Composite Design Pattern*

Podemos agora começar a escrever as classes concretas dos membros do nosso compósito.

Comecemos pelos membros simples: **Folha** e **Fruta**

```
public class Folha : Membro
{
    public Folha() 
        : base("Folha")
    {
    }
}

public class Fruto : Membro
{
    public Fruto(string nome)
        :base(nome)
    {

    }
    public Fruto()
        : base("Fruto")
    {
    }
}
```

Elas herdam de *Membro* e simplesmente passam o seu nome para a classe base.
No caso de *Fruta*, adicionei um outro construtor, caso se pretenda dar um nome especifico à fruta(Banana por exemplo).

Falta escrever as classes dos membros que são compósitos: **Árvore**, **Tronco** e **Galho**

```
public class Arvore : MembroComposto
{
    public Arvore(string nome)
        :base(nome)
    {

    }
    public Arvore() : base("Arvore")
    {
    }
}

public class Tronco : MembroComposto
{
    public Tronco()
        : base("Tronco")
    {
    }
}

public class Galho : MembroComposto
{
    public Galho()
        : base("Galho")
    {
    }
}
```

Elas simplesmente herdam de *MembroComposto* e passam o respectivo nome para a classe base. À classe *Arvore* foi adicionado outro construtor para permitir dar um nome especifico à árvore.

Tendo todas as classes vamos usá-las para compor o nosso compósito: uma Macieira.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Criar algumas folhas
    Membro folha1 = new Folha();
    Membro folha2 = new Folha();
    Membro folha3 = new Folha();
    Membro folha4 = new Folha();

    //Criar algumas frutas
    Membro maca1 = new Fruto("maçã 1");
    Membro maca2 = new Fruto("maçã 2");
    Membro maca3 = new Fruto("maçã 3");
    Membro maca4 = new Fruto("maçã 4");
    Membro maca5 = new Fruto("maçã 5");

    //Criar dois galhos
    MembroComposto galho1 = new Galho();
    MembroComposto galho2 = new Galho();

    //Atribuir maçãs e folhas aos galhos
    galho1.AdicionarMembro(folha1);
    galho1.AdicionarMembro(folha2);
    galho1.AdicionarMembro(maca1);
    galho1.AdicionarMembro(maca2);
    galho1.AdicionarMembro(maca3);

    galho2.AdicionarMembro(folha3);
    galho2.AdicionarMembro(folha4);
    galho2.AdicionarMembro(maca4);
    galho2.AdicionarMembro(maca5);

    //Criar o tronco da maceira
    MembroComposto tronco = new Tronco();

    //Adicionar os galhos ao tronco
    tronco.AdicionarMembro(galho1);
    tronco.AdicionarMembro(galho2);

    //Criar a macieira
    MembroComposto macieira = new Arvore("Macieira");

    //Adicionar o tronco
    macieira.AdicionarMembro(tronco);

    //Imprimir a arvore
    maciera.Imprimir(1);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output:**

> -Macieira
>   --Tronco
>   ---Galho
>   ----Folha
>   ----Folha
>   ----maça 1
>   ----maça 2
>   ----maça 3
>   ---Galho
>   ----Folha
>   ----Folha
>   ----maça 4
>   ----maça 5

Tudo isto pode não responder directamente à sua pergunta mas, na minha opinião, é a abordagem correcta para este tipo de modelo.

Comment: Muito obrigado! A partir do seu exemplo eu consegui resolver o problema. Grato!

Answer (score 4):

Eu vejo dois jeitos de forçar a ordem de execução dos métodos da classe `Arvore`:

• Tornar privados os métodos `AdicionarTronco`, `AdicionarGalho`, `AdicionarFolha` e `AdicionarFruto` e chamá-los apenas em um método público `Construir`.

```
private ITronco AdicionarTronco()
{       
    ...
}

public IGalho AdicionarGalho()
{       
    ...
}

public IGalho AdicionarFolha()
{
    ...
}

public IGalho AdicionarFruto()
{
    ...
}

public void Construir()
{
    AdicionarTronco();
    AdicionarGalho();
    AdicionarFolha();
    AdicionarFruto();
}
```

**Ou**

• Para cada método, criar uma variável privada do tipo Boolean no escopo da classe que irá indicar se os métodos anteriores foram chamados. Por exemplo:

```
public class Arvore
{
    public List<Membro> Membros { get; set; }
    private boolean adicionouTronco;
    private boolean adicionouGalho;
    private boolean adicionouFolha;
    private boolean adicionouFruto; 

    public ITronco AdicionarTronco()
    {       
        Membros.Add(new Tronco());
        adicionouTronco = true;
        return this;
    }

    public IGalho AdicionarGalho()
    {       
        if(!adicionouTronco)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Adicione o tronco antes de adicionar o galho");

        Membros.Add(new Galho());
        adicionouGalho = true;
        return this;
    }

    public IGalho AdicionarFolha()
    {
        if(!adicionouTronco)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Adicione o tronco antes de adicionar o galho");

        if(!adicionouGalho)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Adicione o galho antes de adicionar a folha");

        Membros.Add(new Folha());
        adicionouFolha = true;
        return this;
    }

    public IGalho AdicionarFruto()
    {
        if(!adicionouTronco)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Adicione o tronco antes de adicionar o galho");

        if(!adicionouGalho)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Adicione o galho antes de adicionar a folha");

        if(!adicionouFolha)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Adicione a folha antes de adicionar a fruto");

        Membros.Add(new Fruto());
        adicionouFruto = true;
        return this;
    }

    public void ImprimirArvore() { ... }
}
```

Nesse exemplo eu usei a exceção [InvalidOperationException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.invalidoperationexception(v=vs.110).aspx), pois segundo a documentação:

> A exceção que é lançada quando um chamada de método é inválida para o estado atual do objeto.

Mas você pode usar uma exceção personalizada conforme sua necessidade.

Comment: +1, apesar da segunda solução ser um [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balking_pattern). É difícil responder sem saber exatamente o problema que o @JamesTK quer resolver, mas não daria também pra resolver via _currying_? Você começa com uma função `f(tronco, galho, folha, fruto)`; uma parte do sistema recebe `f` e retorna uma _closure_ `g(galho, folha, fruto)`, e assim sucessivamente, até chegar numa _closure_ `j()`, que pode ser chamada diretamente pra construir o objeto que você quer (não entendo muito de C#, por isso que não posto isso como resposta).

Answer (score 2):

No espírito do comentário que eu postei na [resposta do @MarcusVinicius](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69359/25930), você pode criar uma `ArvoreFactoryFactoryFactoryFactory` (mas obviamente você poderia escolher um nome menos esdrúxulo, `ArvoreSemTronco`):

```
public class ArvoreSemTronco {
    public ArvoreSemGalho AdicionarTronco(Tronco tronco) {
        return ArvoreSemGalho(tronco);
    }
}

public class ArvoreSemGalho {
    Tronco Tronco;

    public ArvoreSemGalho(Tronco tronco) {
        Tronco = tronco;
    }

    public ArvoreSemFolha AdicionarGalho(Galho galho) {
        return ArvoreSemFolha(Tronco, galho);
    }
}

public class ArvoreSemFolha {
    Tronco Tronco;
    Galho Galho;

    public ArvoreSemGalho(Tronco tronco, Galho galho) {
        Tronco = tronco;
        Galho = galho;
    }

    public ArvoreSemFruto AdicionarFolha(Folha folha) {
        return ArvoreSemFruto(Tronco, Galho, folha);
    }
}

public class ArvoreSemFruto {
    Tronco Tronco;
    Galho Galho;
    Folha Folha;

    public ArvoreSemFruto(Tronco tronco, Galho galho, Folha folha) {
        Tronco = tronco;
        Galho = galho;
        Folha = folha
    }

    public Arvore AdicionarFolha(Fruto fruto) {
        return Arvore(Tronco, Galho, Folha, fruto);
    }
}
```

Obviamente, a maior desvantagem dessa abordagem é que você precisa escrever uma quantidade de código quadrática no número de passos intermediários de construção da árvore; você poderia aliviar isso com algum tipo de geração automática de código.

A maior *vantagem*, por outro lado, é que isso permite você ter uma árvore construída pela metade (e passá-la de um lado pro outro, e armazenar nos seus próprios métodos) ao mesmo tempo que erros como chamar os métodos na ordem errada são detectados em tempo de compilação, e não em tempo de execução.

Comment: Da forma como está não é possível adicionar mais do que um Membro. Para que esta abordagem funcione em cada classe, o método `AdicionarXXX()`, deverá retornar a própria classe e teria de ter um método chamado `Build()` que retorne a classe seguinte. Por outro lado é necessário implementar a forma de guardar e obter a árvore com todos os seus membros.

Comment: A pergunta fala _“Após `AdicionarTronco()`, somente `AdicionarGalho()` poderá ser acessado, e `AdicionarTronco()` não poderá mais ser acessado.”_; por isso que eu limitei a colocar só um tronco, por exemplo, mas vendo aqui parece que sim, pra outros objetos pode haver mais de um (e aí sim é necessário fazer algo tipo o `Build()`).

Comment: De qualquer forma, a ideia é essencialmente essa — se for pra incluir mais de uma folha ou mais de um fruto, aí a classe final teria uma `List<Folha>` e uma `List<Fruto>` e os métodos `AdicionarXXX()` retornariam um novo objeto com a folha ou o fruto adicionais. Não é óbvio pra mim se a classe final não poderia ser a própria `Arvore` — contanto que `AdicionarXXX()` retornasse uma nova árvore, ao invés de alterar a árvore existente e retornar `void`, e os outros métodos de `Arvore` tivessem semânticas parecidas de imutabilidade.